# passing the sql resultset to another sqlquery rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get details of users connected to projects.

```
@users=UserProject.find(:all,:conditions => ["project_id=?",@project.id],:select=> "DISTINCT user_id")

@user_details=User.find(@users)
```

but it is failing saying could not find the User with ID=#{some garbage}

Comment: read here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to do your using AR [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

project.rb:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :users, through: :user_projects
  # ...
end
```

user_project.rb:

```
class UserProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
  # ...
end
```

then, you can do simply:

```
@users = @project.users
```